# How to create UIView with custom shape propely?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have to create `UIView` with custom shape, such as triangular, half-rect, etc. 
I used to crop special image to that form and set as a background of my view.
Although it is a popular solution, I am not sure whether it is the most efficient one in terms of sustainability.

On the other hand, I found useful way of solving this problem with `CAShapeLayer()`

Could you please provide pros and cons of both approaches?

Comment: I've used both approaches, and imo I prefer the CAShapeLayer way. Despite requiring a little more effort, it gives me more control over the shape, color, size, tranform, etc.. With the first approach, if the color and/or size of the shape change, I will need to ask the UI designer to re-make the image for me.

Answer (score 0):

CAShapeLayer all the way!

With little effort you can achieve the same result with less memory (RAM) and less maintenance time (if you want to make the triangle thicker for example, you'll need a new image however a small change in code and you have it!). Moreover your app size will be relatively smaller and you don't have to worry about the resolution like the images.

Hope this helps!